# Add layouts to the listview with a button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Android studio to develop my app and i write a little code that add text to listview everytime i press a button, and it work perfectly. This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editText;
    Button addButton;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItem);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        listItems.add("First Item - added on Activity Create");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                listItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now I want code that add layouts to the listview with a button, I tried to do it and failed, how do I do it?

Comment: which type of layout do you want to add and what will be the usage?

Comment: Relativ layout, does it matter and why?

Answer (score 0):

I've written an extremely basic example here that assumes the layout (row) you want to add to your `ListView` has two `TextView`s since I do not know from your question what kind of object/data you want in your rows. First, define a layout in your layouts folder. This layout represents the row that you're going to insert into your `ListView`:

my_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- add images or whatever content you want to your row -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/my_text1"
        android:id="@+id/my_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Next, define an object that represents the data for your row layout.

```
public class MyRowItem 
{
    private String text1;
    private String text2;

    public MyRowItem(String text1, String text2) 
    {
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.text2 = text2;
    }

    public String getText1() 
    {
        return text1;
    }

    public String getText2() 
    {
        return text2;
    }
}
```

Now, instead of using a simple `ArrayAdapter` of Strings, you will need to create a custom adapter for your items, in this case, the different rows you're going to add to your `ListView`. For example:

```
    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyRowItem> implements View.OnClickListener
    {   

        private ArrayList<MyRowItem> rowItems;

        private static class ViewHolder 
        {
            TextView text1;
            TextView text2;
        }

        public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<MyRowItems> items, Context context) 
        {
            super(context, R.layout.my_row, rowItems);
            this.rowItems = rowItems;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)  
        {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            MyRowItem rowItem = getItem(position);
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            final View result;
            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
                viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_text1);
                viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_text2);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } 
            else 
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

            viewHolder.text1.setText(rowItem.getText1());
            viewHolder.text2.setText(rowItem.getText1());
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

In this particular example, we could replace your original `listItems` with a list of `MyRowItem`s. For example,

`listItems.add(new MyRowItem("hello", "world");`

Now you can use your custom adapter in your activity or fragment. So you would replace your adapter instantiation with:

`adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(listItems, this);`

and in your button's `onClickListener`:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
{
    public void onClick(View v)  
    {
        listItems.add(new MyRowItem("new item", editText.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

I know this example is a bit basic, but hopefully it helps you get started.

Comment: i dont know what im doing wrong, but i get errors on few things in the custom adapter:                                                                                                                    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<MyRowItems> items, Context context)
        {
            super(context, R.layout.my_row, rowItems);
            this.rowItems = rowItems;
        }   the Customadapter is error and the MyRowItem is error and rowItems is error     + the v.getcontext is error/ what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you hover over the error and see what the error says? It could be that you need another constructor.

Comment: on the CustomAdapter the error is invalid method decleration, return type required.                                                                                                                          on the MyRowItems the error is cant resolve symbol.                                                on the rowItems the error is cannot reference mycustomadapter.rowitems before supertype constructor has been called.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I made some typographical errors. The name of the constructor should be `public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<MyRowItem> items, Context context)`. I've edited my answer. (originally, i wrote `public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<MyRowItems> items, Context context)`

Comment: `v.getContext` should be `v.getContext()`. Apologies for the typos. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: @ohadavraham please see the two comments above. After those fixes, the code should compile correctly.